# How to get C++ compiled wasm to access local filesystem in an Electron app

Tags: c++, file-io, electron, filesystems, webassembly

I am building an `electron` app using C++ libraries compiled to `wasm` that needs to access the local filesystem (NOT the Emscripten virtual file system) to open/edit any arbitrary file selected by the user. However, I cannot find a way to do it, other than to have javascript open the file, and pass the data to the wasm code. It would be much easier to have `wasm` open the file itself.

Is it possible to get `wasm` in an electron app access the local filesystem? If so, how?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I read files from the disk by using Webassembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45535301/can-i-read-files-from-the-disk-by-using-webassembly)

Comment: @JorgeLópez The big difference for me is that I need to open/edit any arbitrary file selected by the user.